# Angular's Change Detection: Why does assigning the result to an additional variable before assigning it to the main variable result in undefined?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In the given code snippet, there is an observable operation to fetch products asynchronously. When assigning the result to an additional variable (`productList`) before assigning it to the main variable (`productDetailTable`), the dropdown momentarily shows `undefined`. However, after clicking multiple times, the options are eventually displayed. On the other hand, directly assigning the result to the main variable (`productDetailTable`) instantly populates the dropdown.

Code that momentarily shows `undefined`:

```js
this.productList = await this.ProductService.getProductsById(projectId).toPromise();
this.productDetailTable = this.productList;
```

Code that instantly populates the dropdown:

```js
this.productDetailTable = await this.ProductService.getProductsById(projectId).toPromise();
```

Dropdown in the template:

```html
<ng-multiselect-dropdown 
    [placeholder]="'aaaaaaaaaa'" 
    formControlName="aaaaaaaaaa"
    [settings]="dropdownSettings"
    [data]="productDetailTable" 
    class="singleselect" 
    [(ngModel)]="aaaaaaaaaaaaa"
    [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
</ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definition from [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

> Await expressions make promise-returning functions behave as though
> they're synchronous by suspending execution until the returned promise
> is fulfilled or rejected.

your code:

```
this.productList = await this.ProductService.getProductsById(projectId).toPromise();
```

This piece of code will return a `promise-returning` function that will be resolved when the api call comes back, then move on to evaluate the next expression. which is

```
this.productDetailTable = this.productList;
```

By the time the above expression is evaluated, the promise is still pending (and `this.productList` is still undefined). That's why the variable `productDetailTable` is `undefined` initially.

In your other code, the variable `productDetailTable` is defined to wait for the api call, so a value won't be assigned until the api comes back.

Comment: understood the issue. thanks a lot Wen for taking the time to help me :)